# wordpress edit specific page html

Tags: wordpress

For example I'm create new page in wordpress "page3" I want edit html and css of this page and add for example my contacs, how to do this ?
I'm searching in theme options, but no resut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the page.php file but what you do to it will effect all other pages. Or you can duplciate the page.php file and call it page-3.php (Or whatever your "Page3" page ID number is). Be sure to keep the calls for the header and footer and the tops and bottoms of your page .

Comment: Where do you get the pageID? or can that also page the page name?